# PHP lists files that don't exist

Tags: php, ubuntu, grav

I'm running [Grav CMS](https://getgrav.org/) on a Linode Ubuntu 16.04 server where PHP7 (php-fpm + nginx) returns cached results when listing directory contents. I first encountered the problem with [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php), but it isn't limited to that class - the same problem appears when I use [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

Basically what happens is that any time I sync new content to the server, whether I use rsync or FTP, PHP will return the old contents of a particular folder.I've tried calling [`clearstatcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php), but it didn't help – even if I called it from the appropriate PHP file, just before I scanned the directory.

`touch`'ing the files to update their mtime doesn't help either. Restarting the php-fpm service does work, however.

Is it possible that PHP caches the contents of the directory in some other way? Could it be the file system that is fooling PHP somehow?

Comment: Look in the nginx.conf and make sure sendfile, is set to off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem I was having wasn't due to the OS or PHP, but to the Grav CMS itself – specifically how it caches page objects. It doesn't invalidate cached pages if all that had changed was the associated media files. Turning off the global cache setting for Grav helped this issue, but I've also opened [an issue on the Grav repo](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/1080) to see if this is inteded behaviour or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is but it's not something I would use in production.

Run sync first: `$ sync`
This command writes any cache data that hasn't been written to the disk out to the disk.

Free pagecache:`echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Free dentries and inodes: `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Free pagecache, dentries and inodes: `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

That being said I would also take a look at `realpath_cache`.

Comment: It turned out the issue was with the system I was using (Grav CMS), and how it cached page objects. I'll edit the question and provide my own answer with the solution, but thanks for your answer!